# Scrolling doesn't work on Windows Phone fullpage.js

Tags: jquery, windows, html, css, fullpage.js

http://syruptest.com/tacobell/inner.html

I m working on this page and us fullpage.js jquery plugin but normal scroll is not happening on windows phone but my page work on apple devices and android devices.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it needs a bugfix in slimscroll.js. Looking at the website from link, did you get the latest version of slimscroll from github? It seems that the file has changed on the 4th of june:

https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/vendors/jquery.slimscroll.min.js

and look:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/489